# Move while keeping the original object

Tags: c++, memory, copy, move, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> a = {1.0,2.1,3.3};
    vector<double> b = {5.8};

    // Do stuff ...

    b = move(a);

    cout << "a.size() = " << a.size() << "\n";
    cout << "b.size() = " << b.size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
a.size() = 0
b.size() = 3
```

I understand this output but I would wish `a` would still point to the same original data. How can I "move" `a` to `b` (to avoid losing time copying) while being able to use both `a` and `b` as if one was a reference of the other? I can't use a reference though as it must changes what it is referencing to.

I could use pointers

```
int main()
{
    vector<double>* a = new vector<double>;
    vector<double>* b = new vector<double>;
    a->push_back(1.0);
    a->push_back(2.1);
    a->push_back(3.3);
    b->push_back(5.8);

    // Do stuff ...

    b = a;

    cout << "a->size() = " << a->size() << "\n";
    cout << "b->size() = " << b->size() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
a->size() = 3
b->size() = 3
```

but, in a much large code of mine, I am using `a` and `b` not as pointers and I would mind having to change the entire code only for this move. Is there a solution?

Comment: Use a reference or a pointer?

Comment: If you move into a new apartment does that mean all your stuff is accessible in the new and old apartment?

Comment: When you move a thing from A to B, it is no longer found at A. I don't think you understand what `move` does.

Comment: So you want to have a reference without actually having a reference? Is this an XY problem?

Comment: A vector *owns* its buffer. There's no sharing possible.

Comment: [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) will do what you want but an actual use case of what you really need would help.

Comment: `std::move(a)` is saying: this thing `a` is a temporary, its going to be destroyed any second now, if you want to steal it's contents no-one is going to notice because it's not going to be there anymore.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::ref` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I am not sure I understand why my questions has such a bad reception and therefore, I don't really know how to edit it. Would you advice me to let it as it is and let you make an answer out of your comment or should I simply delete my question?

Comment: @Remi.b Might be best.  I'm not sure why it was down voted but it could be because people didn't think you researched what happened when you actually move something.

Comment: "*It looks like the `move` cleaned up what `a` was pointing to. Is it what's happening? Why would it do that?*" This question shows no research effort. It looks like OP didn't even read the description of the tags they used (e.g. `move-semantics`).

Comment: @Remi.b Since you cleaned it up would you like me to answer the Q?

Comment: @melpomene I've edited it that just before your comment. I realized that was the part that got me this reception. It is true that I naively confused the concepts of `std::ref` and `std::move` when writing this question (and I had never heard of `std::ref` before Nathan's comment).

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure, sounds like it is better that removing the question altogether! I personally got my answer but I feel this question may eventually help future readers (as I've had a hard time to find the info myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how vectors manage their memory.

Whether you're using simple assignment or a move, you will never get two different vectors pointing to the same data in memory. In the assignment case, any data in the destination is deleted, then copies of the data in the source are made and added to the destination. In the move case, any data in destination is deleted, then the data in the source is removed from the source and added to the destination.

To answer your question "How can I move a to b (to avoid losing time copying) while being able to use both a and b as if one was a reference of the other?" - You should not move a to b at all (so no time spent copying the data), and then define b either as a reference to a or a pointer to a:

```
vector<double> a = {1.0,2.1,3.3};
vector<double>& b_ref = a;
vector<double>* b_ptr = &a;
```

Both b_ref and b_ptr allow access to the data in a without making any copies.